# How to automatically load .so/.dll from any class in a java project?

Tags: java

Suppose I'm doing a java library that has to load a .so/.dll at its initialization, but I don't know which classes the user will use, so I cannot simply put

```
static{
    loadSoFromMyJar();
}
```

on the one that is gonna be used.

The easiest solution I thought was by doing it in a class and subclassing all the classes from this one, but I also think this is not the best solution.

What would be a good solution here?

Comment: If that native library really must be loaded, regardless of which class is used, then putting `static { loadSoFromMyJar(); }` into every class *is* feasible. It’s not different to putting `extends WhatEver` into every class, except the latter has serious drawbacks.

Comment: How is your library loaded in the application? Are you planning to create `jar` files? Is there some kind of plugin system you wrote?

Comment: @Holger which drawbacks?

Comment: @Progman it could be loaded in any way. Could be in a .jar file, or be used in another project in another way

Comment: A serious drawback of `extends Whatever` is that the class cannot extend any other class.

Comment: I would just define an initiatialization method and require that the application calls it before using the library.

Answer (score 2):

Make `loadSoFromMyJar` idempotent and add it in a static initialiser on all classes with `native` members.